Headless standalone Unity application in a docker container with GPU acceleration (Repost from SO)
I am trying to run a containerized Unity application as a simulation environment for RL agents. The simulation is fairly demanding so it requires GPU acceleration. This excludes Xvfb AFAIK. Furthermore, I will eventually be deploying the container to a cluster (which is why I need the docker container) so I cannot rely on a running host X server. Basically, I want this, without having to create an X server on the host.
I can run my application like so xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension GLX +render -noreset" ./my_unity_application.x86_64 -batchmode. This only gets me around 5fps instead of the 60 I get when I run it outside of the container because xvfb-run uses the LLVMpipe software rasterizer. I've tried VirtualGL (xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension GLX +render -noreset" vglrun -d ":99" ./my_unity_application.x86_64 -batchmode) but it doesn't seem to make a difference (still llvmpipe renderer).
Other dead ends:

Setting LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1 will not work because this restricts the OpenGL version to 1.4 which is lower than the version required by Unity (3.2)
Launching X inside docker. Works with the dummy driver from the xserver-xorg-video-dummy package but again falls back on software rasterization.
Wayland? I can also run the application inside of the container with weston -B headless-backend.so --use-gl. In Wayland, as far as I understand, applications are themselves responsible for making rendering calls to rendering libraries such as OpenGL. I have installed libegl1-mesa and libegl1 to the container but ./my_unity_application.x86_64 -batchmode -logfile - still outputs Renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits).
Xdummy + vglrun same issue (Renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits))

Summary: how do I run a Unity application with GPU-accelerated rendering in a docker container that cannot rely on a host X server?

TigerVNC starting from 1.14.0 supports hardware accelerated OpenGL and Vulkan on drivers that supports GBM.  It seems that it also requires that your gpu driver supports DRI3, excluding proprietary nvidia drivers (if I understand correctly).
(I wasn't able to test this.  I'm trying to solve a similar problem as you do, tried everything that you plus tigervnc that still doesn't work because of the gpu driver.)

Unfortunately, I don't think I'll be able to get around using proprietary drivers.
